# Interstate Karnataka Tamul Nadu permit charges

Tags: india, fees-and-charges

We are planning to visit Trichunapalli from Bangalore. We will be going by a 36 seater mini bus. What will be the inter state permit charges to be paid at the Hosur check post?

Answer (score 2):

[Government of Tamil Nadu State Transport Authority](http://www.tn.gov.in/sta/t2.html)

> Tax Rates for Contract Carriages
>
> Omni Bus
>
> Based on Seating Capacity
>
> a) Not more than 36 (other than driver) for every square meter of floor area of the vehicle Rs.4900/-
>
> b) More than 36 persons (Other than driver) for ever person (Other than the driver) = Rs.3000/-